# Всегда выводит ветвь true

Tags: javascript

Разметка html.

```
<div id="type" class="">Красный клен</div>
```

Есть массив исключений и проверяемое поле.

```
var exceptions = ["красный", "синий", "белый"];
var type = [document.getElementById(`type`).innerHTML];
```

Если в `type` присутствует любой из элементов массива `exceptions`, то `if` не должен срабатывать. Он у меня всегда выводит что 'не содержит'. Почему так?

```
    market_exceptions.some(q => {
        if (!type[0].startsWith(q)) {
            c('не содержит');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Сделайте `console.log(type)`, что вывело?

Comment: а содержимое элемента с id `type` точно в таком же регистре как и значение из массива exceptions?

Comment: Если написать `console.log(type)` выведет например красный лист или желтый шланг.

Comment: Добавьте в пример html-код, который используется в этом примере.

Comment: Что такое `startsWith`? Приведите реализацию. Либо этот метод не определен, либо определен неправильно, либо неправильно реализован (всегда возвращает `false`). И что содержится в `market_exceptions`?

Comment: @smellyshovel https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith стандартный метод строки

Comment: @MegaRoks ну так `'Красный' !== 'красный'`

Comment: @AlexeyTen а... Первый раз слышу о нем :)

Comment: @smellyshovel, уже давно добавили вместе c `trim`, и `endsWith`

Answer (score 0):

Так как метод [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) регистрозависимый, он считает строки с разным регистром разными, например: `красный` - `Красный`

Чтобы исправить это необходимо привести строки к одному регистру, либо хранить все допустимые варианты строк.

Привести к одному регистру можно с помощью функций [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) и [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Код станет выглядеть так:

```
var currentType = type[0].toLowerCase(); // так как в market_exceptions элементы уже в нижнем регистре достаточно привести только проверяемую строку
market_exceptions.some(q => {
    if (!currentType.startsWith(q)) {
        c('не содержит');
    }
});
```